# Casting query result to STRING in OrientDB

Tags: sql, casting, subquery, orientdb

As a test, I'm running the query

```
orientdb {pumpup}> select objectId from post where objectId="6LTMvSXfM2"

----+-----+----------
#   |@RID |objectId
----+-----+----------
0   |#-2:1|6LTMvSXfM2
----+-----+----------

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.002 sec(s).
```

But when it's not quoted, it fails, and slowly

```
orientdb {pumpup}> select objectId from post where objectId=6LTMvSXfM2


0 item(s) found. Query executed in 59.216 sec(s).
```

My question is how do I wrap the result of a query as a string, so I can wrap the string like so

```
select from post where objectId=(select objectId from post where objectId="6LTMvSXfM2")
```

What's the proper way to cast the result of a subquery to string format?

Comment: It should fail quickly with a syntax error without the quotes, I think.

Comment: It doesn't fail because 6LTMvSXfM2 could be the name of a field. OrientDB works also in schema-less mode. I don't understand the meaning of the sub-query.

Comment: In migrating my data (prior to ETL), I have a `Notification` for when people `Like` a `Post`. The Notification contains the objectId of the Like, and the Like contains the objectId of the Post. I need to get the Post from the Notification, so I do `select from post where objectId=(select post.objectId from like where objectId="6LTMvSXfM2")`, and from there I can get the `@rid`. But without being able to wrap the result of the subquery as a string, it always fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subquery is supposed to return a result set, not a single value, so you cannot cast it to string.

To obtain the result you are expecting you should use the "in" operator instead of "=" :

SELECT FROM post WHERE objectId **IN** (select objectId from post where objectId="6LTMvSXfM2")

In this case the "objectId" in the parent query (that is a string) will be matched to the "objectId" of every record returned by the subquery, that already is a string.

(anyway, this query does not actually make sense ;-) you are executing a subquery where you don't need it)